# Font Awesome 5 Social Media Icons Appearing as Flashing ! and?

Tags: font-awesome, erb

I have the `font_awesome5_rails` gem installed on my app and have some of the icons working, but the social media icons are flashing between an exclamation mark (!) and a question mark (?).

You can see the problem on my heroku staging site here:  https://ssm-staging.herokuapp.com/

The Icons in the header are working perfectly with this ERB:

```
<%= link_to home_house_path do %>
  <%= fa_icon "home", id: "house-icon", class: "header-icon color-house" %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to home_spouse_path do %>
  <%= fa_icon "ring", id: "spouse-icon", class: "header-icon color-spouse" %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to home_kids_path do %>
  <%= fa_icon "baby", id: "kids-icon", class: "header-icon color-kids" %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to home_self_path do %>
  <%= fa_icon "spa", id: "self-icon", class: "header-icon color-self" %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to blogs_path do %>
  <%= fa_icon "pen-fancy", id: "blog-icon", class: "header-icon color-neutral" %>
<% end %>
```

But the social media ones (except the last one, which works fine) in the footer are glitching with this ERB:

```
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TheStaySaneMom/" target="_blank"><%= fa_icon "facebook-square", class: "social-icon" %></a>
          <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/theStaySaneMom/" target="_blank"><%= fa_icon "pinterest-square", class: "social-icon" %></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/theStaySaneMom/" target="_blank"><%= fa_icon "instagram", class: "social-icon" %></a>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_g4NFVoQi4t2PbA23q0_VQ" target="_blank"><%= fa_icon "youtube", class: "social-icon" %></a>
          <a href="https://pages.convertkit.com/8d96562969/8204904d02" target="_blank>"><%= fa_icon "amazon", class: "social-icon" %></a>
          <%= mail_to("liz@theStaySaneMom.com") do %><%= fa_icon "envelope", class: "social-icon color-black" %><% end %>
```

I've tried double checking the icon names on the [Font Awesome Site](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery) but they all check out.

Can anyone see what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason an ERB statement inside an `<a>` link caused the glitch, so when I switched them to `<i class="fab fa-facebook social-icon"></i>` it worked just fine.

Still not sure why, but this is what I found to work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I've just had this issue and your question helped me.

I'm using the javascript package `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free` but its the same problem.

FontAwesome 5 javascript converts the `<i>` tag into an svg and the flashing question/exclamation mark is for when an icon cannot be found. There must be something in the javascript which validates the class (`fa-facebook`) and also validates the HTML tag (`<i>`). If you don't use an `<i>` tag, or the icon doesn't exist (my case was a spelling mistake), you get the flashing error.

```
<i class="fas fa-check"></i>
<span class="fas fa-check"></span>
```

Becomes

```html
 <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-check fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="check" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">... valid svg here...</svg>
<!-- <i class="fas fa-check"></i> -->

<svg class="svg-inline--fa  fa-w-16" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="undefined" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
... valid svg here...</svg>
<!-- <span class="fas fa-check">span</span> -->
```

Notice the class name for the SVG is missing and the HTML I had is added as a comment.

Hope that helps people out.